# Importing a CSV file into Spyder from a mac

Tags: python, pandas, spyder

I'm just getting started with learning how utilize Spyder. I'm utilizing a mac to do so, if that makes any difference. I'm having a horrible time opening up a csv file on my computer. I'm wondering if someone can tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Here's the code I'm using:

```
import pandas as pd
one = pd.read_csv("~/Documents/2017Data/2017DATA.csv")
```

I get the following error when I execute the statements:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb0 in position 592: invalid start byte

Comment: You likely need to set the `encoding`: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use different encoding -

```
import pandas as pd
one = pd.read_csv("~/Documents/2017Data/2017DATA.csv", encoding = "ISO-8859-1")
```